# Scala, Swing and MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, swing, scala

I found some informations about using Swing with Scala in Programming in Scala book. I also found some basic informations here: http://www.scala-lang.org/sid/8 . But there are no informations about how to build bigger application based on Swing. Than I found some informations in German (but code is in Scala;)): http://www.scalatutorial.de/topic123.html . And it is good... but still, it is good for small applications. I'm going to wrote something bigger. So I want to make not one, but few models, and few views for each, like in Ruby on Rails. Do you know some good tutorials or egsamples which may help me do it properly?

Answer (score 0):

here's a program using scala-swing: https://github.com/lrytz/pacman, also rather small though.

Comment: Your answer does not contain any explanation or example and the link does not work.